# How to make flashing text in Css?

Tags: html, css

I have an understanding that most web browsers do not support the flashing text animation anymore with the following code: `<blink> your text</blink>`, however, are there other methods that provide the flashing animation for the text in html or css?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! 
You can use CSS3 animations to handle that now.

HTML:

```
 <h1 class="flash">Look at me flash</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.flash {
   animation-name: flash;
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes flash {
    from {color: red;}
    to {color: black;}
}
```

[Here's a link to a codepen](http://codepen.io/SamPedley/pen/qEZRxv) to see it in action.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not as efficient as @SupperSam's answer, but maybe a little bit more cross-browser friendly.
You could use JS (jQuery) to achieve the flashing effect by toggling a class.

eg.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.flash').toggleClass('active');
  }, 500);
});
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/8yned9f9/